# Forcing a failed mvn flyway:migrate to skip failed schema migration, and try executing next schema

Tags: postgresql, maven, flyway

I was trying to run `flyway:migrate` on my projects `postgres database`. I have made the changes to a table manually and because of that the schema migration using flyway is failing, which is blocking next schema migration execution.

```
table : foo  

required_change : ALTER TABLE foo ALTER COLUMN id DROP NOT NULL 

current_schema_version : 2

next_schema_version : 3
```

Error:

```
[ERROR] com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Migration of schema "public" to version 3 failed! Changes successfully rolled back.
```

How could I skip failing schema and make `flyway:migrate` execute next schema defined?

Answer (score 1):

It might be simplest to undo the manual change so that Flyway can run successfully.  For example, if you dropped the column then add it back in, then run the Flyway script to drop it.

Answer (score 0):

So I found one possible solution to this problem, which goes as follows:

(1). In mysql database there is a table *schema_version*, which maintains the migration version number , it's status and other related information. 
for ex.

mysql> desc schema_version;

version_rank
installed_rank
version
description
type
script
checksum
installed_by
installed_on
execution_time
success

for a failed migration the success field values stores 0, to override that and execute the next flyway:migration you can manually set the value to 1 (this would make sure, you don't lose the data stored on the table you created manually , when migration failed.

(2). Adding following on your pom.xml while running flyway:migration temporarily (while testing) also helps.

`<validateOnMigrate>false</validateOnMigrate>`